# Google Cloud : Unable to establish MySql DB connection from PHP

Tags: php, mysql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I have successfully configured App Engine & Web App. I could load PHP page not having DB connection successfully.
Problem comes while I am attempting to establish MySQL DB connection. Just to note, I have also successfully created DB by import.
Below is piece of PHP which is attempting to connect MySQL -

```
    <?php 

    $con = mysqli_connect(null, 'root', null,'dbname',0,':/cloudsql/<instance connection name>');

    if (mysqli_connect_error($con)) {
        die('Connect Error myname (' . mysqli_connect_errno($con) . ') '  . 
mysqli_connect_error($con));
    }
    echo "Connection OK";
    ?>
```

is composed like this - 
Project id:Compute Engine:DB instance name

But, I am getting below error -

Unable to find the socket transport "unix" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?

What is precisely going wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

As I was checking multiple posts, but with my trial & error attempts I could establish connection. Below, is mysqli_connect which worked for me.

```
$con = mysqli_connect(null, 'root', '<password>','<dbname>',null,'/cloudsql/<project id>:<computing engine>:<instance name>');
```

':' is removed from the socket string.
'password' was explicitly required.